# Query Delete not work when use $_GET or $_SESSION but Work on general Variable

Tags: php, mysql

```
 $kode='12345';
 echo $query01="DELETE FROM t_barang where kd_barang='".$kode."'";
```

[image]
the above work code

below doesn't work code
its just not doing anything

```
$_GET['kode'];
echo $query01="DELETE FROM t_barang where kd_barang='".$_GET['kode']."' " ;
```

[image]

Comment: look at the query, you have extra quote marks

Comment: What do you mean my "does not doing anything". It is doing exactly what it sups to be done.

Comment: Do **not** use `"` in your URL. Just do `?kode=12345`, for example.

Comment: M H Rasel .... its not delete any row

Comment: Also, yeah, it is doing exactly what it's supposed to... just as @MHRasel pointed out

Comment: Zeke this one work  $kode='12345';.... the problem this one $_GET['kode'];

Comment: I know... I'm telling you to look at the URL, not the code. Do **not** use quote marks in URLs. Unless you really need them, but this is not the case.

Comment: Never mind what it's doing: it's an SQL injection waiting to happen.

Comment: my code before edit :  echo '<a href=phapusb.php?kode="' . $row['kd_barang'] . '">Hapus</a>'; ?>  and this one after edit :  echo '<a href=phapusb.php?kode=12345>Hapus</a>'; ?> and its work but how i suppose to relate with $row ?

Comment: `echo '<a href="phapusb.php?kode='.$row['kd_barang'].'">Hapus</a>';` should do the trick.

Comment: thanks Zeke it's work.... i lack from that think... can you give me link to me for more understand how to use quote ?

Comment: the issue is your HTML as much as your php https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML

Comment: You're welcome @Aris. Please do remember that you have a lot more issues than just what you asked for... so please do your research. About the quote marks, you can learn about that almost anywhere, a Google search or browsing StackOverflow will be helpful.

Comment: @Aris if that solved your problem, please mark the answer as correct so other people can find the solution more easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently part of the code (I believe in another file) is not posted, but added in the comments. I quote what the asker commented:

> my code before edit : `echo '<a href=phapusb.php?kode="' . $row['kd_barang'] . '">Hapus</a>'; ?>` and this one after edit : `echo '<a href=phapusb.php?kode=12345>Hapus</a>'; ?>` and its work but how i suppose to relate with $row ? - Aris

The solution is to use the following code instead:

```
echo '<a href="phapusb.php?kode='.$row['kd_barang'].'">Hapus</a>';
```